# JQuery Autocomplete not showing inside Bootstrap row division

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My Autocomplete works great when it is on a stand-alone HTML or ASPx page.
When the control is inside a row division, the webservice returns but seems to hang.  While I can place the control outside a div row, it changes the layout of the page.  Any idea why, and is there a work-around?

This examples DOES NOT display results:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:4px;">
   <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" id="inventorySearch" runat="server" class="form-control" /></div>
   <div class="col-md-2"><input type="number" id="txtQuantity" name="txtQuantity" runat="server" class="form-control" min="0" max="9999" value="0" /></div>
   <div class="col-md-1" style="text-align:left;"><asp:Button ID="btnAddBillofMaterials" runat="server" CssClass="logoutbutton" Text="Add Item" OnClick="btnAddBillofMaterials_Click" /></div>
</div>
```

And this does display dropdown combo box:

```
 Search: <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" id="inventorySearch" runat="server" class="form-control" /></div>
```

Comment: Can you include an example of the code where it's working and then the change that causes it to not work?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/qad621nj/)

Answer (score 0):

After hours of experimenting I gave up and placed the search control inside it's own simple div tag. It works.  Some things are not worth the effort to figure out why they don't work.  I think it's that too much was going on inside the other divs.